# Java YAML best way to read a dynamically changing file

Tags: java, yaml

I am trying to find the best way to read a YAML file in Java. I am not sure which parser is the best one to use, but currently my solution to read a dynamic (if users want to add more content to the file, the next time the program loads) is a series of for loops, converting to and from ArrayLists and hashmaps and parsing the raw string.

ex:

```
HashMap<Object, Object> perWaveHashMap = (HashMap)waveConfiguration.getList("waves").get(wave); //wave-1
        for(Object mobObject : perWaveHashMap.values()){
            ArrayList<Object> mobObjectArrayList = (ArrayList) mobObject;
            for(Object mob : mobObjectArrayList){
                HashMap<Object, Object> mobHashMap = (HashMap)mob;
                String mobNameString = null;
                for(Object mobName : mobHashMap.keySet()){
                    mobNameString = mobName.toString();
                }
                for(Object mobAttribute : mobHashMap.values()){
                    HashMap<Object, Object> attributesToGive = (HashMap)mobAttribute;
                    final ArrayList<Object> attributeList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(Object attribute : attributesToGive.values()){
                        attributeList.add(attribute);
                    }
                    assert mobNameString != null;
                    final String finalMobNameString = mobNameString;

                    System.out.println("Final Mob Name String: " + finalMobNameString);
                    if(finalMobNameString.equalsIgnoreCase("vintr")){
                        Mobs.isSpecialBossWave =true;
                        new Vintr();
                    } else {
                        if (attributeList.size() == 1) {
                            Mobs.addMobs((int) attributeList.get(0), EntityType.valueOf(finalMobNameString.toUpperCase()));
                        } else if (attributeList.size() == 2) {
                            Mobs.addMobs((int) attributeList.get(0), EntityType.valueOf(finalMobNameString.toUpperCase()), (int) attributeList.get(1));
                        } else if (attributeList.size() == 3) {
                            Mobs.addMobs((int) attributeList.get(0), EntityType.valueOf(finalMobNameString.toUpperCase()), (int) attributeList.get(1), (boolean) attributeList.get(2));
                        } else if (attributeList.size() == 4) {
                            Mobs.addMobs((int) attributeList.get(0), EntityType.valueOf(finalMobNameString.toUpperCase()), (int) attributeList.get(1), (boolean) attributeList.get(2), (boolean) attributeList.get(3));
                        } else if (attributeList.size() == 5) {
                            Mobs.addMobs((int) attributeList.get(0), EntityType.valueOf(finalMobNameString.toUpperCase()), (int) attributeList.get(1), (boolean) attributeList.get(2), (boolean) attributeList.get(3), (boolean) attributeList.get(4));
                        } else if (attributeList.size() == 6) {
                            Mobs.addMobs((int) attributeList.get(0), EntityType.valueOf(finalMobNameString.toUpperCase()), (int) attributeList.get(1), (boolean) attributeList.get(2), (boolean) attributeList.get(3), (boolean) attributeList.get(4), (boolean) attributeList.get(5));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Basically, the YML file looks like this:

```
waves:
  - 1:
    - zombie:
        amount: 1
        modifier: 2
        boss: false
        beeline: false
  - 1:
    - spider:
        amount: 12
        modifier: 2
        boss: false
        beeline: false
        hunter: true
  -2 :
    - mobname:
        -options
```

The way my code is right now, allows me to add as many 'waves' as I want, and as many mobs that I want in each wave. I find the way I am doing the code really ugly and hard to work with though and am looking for a better way to solve this problem.

Any help is welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Unclear requirements. What does it mean "dynamic" in the first place? Then, are you asking for a way to parse YAML? (Answer: use SnakeYAML) Do you need to deserialize text into domain objects? (Suggestion: use YamlBeans)

Comment: I only read the File once, every time I start the program. Dynamic in the sense that it can be changed and the next time the program loads it must read the new changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use snakeyaml to read a yaml file into a POJO.

```
File configFile = new File(configFilename);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(configFile);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(Config.class));
Config config = yaml.loadAs(fis, Config.class);
```

Your Config class can be like:

```
public class Config {

     List<Wave> waves;

     public List<Wave> getWaves() {
          return waves;
     }
}

// similarly define other classes for the Wave etc...
```

Read the documentation at : https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Home

Comment: The file wont change during runtime, I am really just looking for a cleaner way to read the file and all its fields without having to nest a bunch of for loops and cast to hashmaps/arrays. If possible.